# Tcpdump captured traffic for GRE reassembled packets

Tags: sockets, system-calls, tcpdump, libpcap, tunneling

Suppose there is a GRE tunnel logical interface (e.g. gre0) configured on Linux 4.6 kernel.

```
sudo ip tunnel add gre0 mode gre remote 10.10.10.1 local 172.168.1.1
```

Execute tcpdump as follows `tcpdump -i gre0`. From my understanding tcpdump/libpcap will open an AF_PACKET raw socket to capture incoming/outgoing packets on gre0.

What about if packets are fragmented when sent towards us from the remote GRE tunnel end-point ? Are they reassembled on our Linux box kernel before being sent over the AF_PACKET raw socket ?

Edit: digging into implementation, the gre packet processing is done in the context of `ip_local_deliver()` function since when the `gre, ip_gre` module is loaded in kernel space there is not a specific protocol handler registered for gre packet handling at `struct ptype` level

```
root@ubuntu:/root# lsmod | grep gre
ip_gre                 24576  0
gre                    16384  1 ip_gre
ip_tunnel              24576  1 ip_gre
root@ubuntu:/root# 
root@ubuntu:/root# 
root@ubuntu:/root# cat /proc/net/ptype 
Type Device      Function
0800          ip_rcv
0806          arp_rcv
86dd          ipv6_rcv
root@ubuntu:/root#
```